# Struct indexing

Tags: c#, struct

I am new to C# and I do not understand this example with Priority Queue

First comes struct

```
public struct pqItem 
{
    public int priority;
    public string name;
}
```

then modified class

```
public class PQueue : Queue 
{
    public PQueue : base() {}

    public override object Dequeue() 
    {
      object [] items;
      int x, min, minindex;
      items = this.ToArray();
      min = (pqItem)items[0].priority;
      for(int x = 1; x <= items.GetUpperbound(0); x++)
        if ((pqItem)items[x].Priority < min) 
        {
          min = (pqItem)items[x].Priority;
          minindex = x;
        }
```

I do not understand how struct indexing works here.

```
min = (pqItem)items[0].priority;
```

Why not (pqItem).items[0]?The code is from McMillan's boook Data structures and algorithms.

Comment: It would help if we were looking at real code rather than free-typed code that won't compile.

Comment: This has nothing to do with indexing. This will (try to) cast the contents of `items[x]` into a `pqItem` struct before calling `.Priority`. It's bad code too. If you know the type, define the array using the *correct* type, not `object`, ie use `pqItem[] items;`

Comment: (pqItem)items[0] is an object. priority is an integer which is what you want to assign to min

Comment: `(pqItem)items[0].priority` is `((pqItem) items[0]).priority` with (technically) superfluous parentheses omitted.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have copied the code from the book.Can you explain why it is bad?Thnx.

Comment: @RichardRublev what book ?? Are you reading a pre-2005 book? Or something translated from VB6? .NET containers use *generics* so they don't have to use `object` or cast. The array should be defined as `pqItem[] items;`. Peopel *don't* use `GetUpperBound(0)` with single dimensional arrays. They use `.Length`. That `ToArray()` method should return a `pqItem` array. Never mind that the entire block is superflous - with LINQ you can just select the minimum value with [Min](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549416(v=vs.110).aspx) like this: `items.Min(it=>it.Priority)`. LINQ added in 2008

Comment: @RichardRublev googling for the `for` line returns this https://www.slideshare.net/helghareeb/lecturenotes06dsa. Googling for phrases from this leads to [this out-of-print 2007 book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/data-structures-and-algorithms-using-c/B5BF0A10FEF6710B02F5A9C7C14B7BD2). All you need to check is [the Amazon Reviews](https://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Using-C/dp/0521670152). It's **HARD** to get 2/5 even in Amazon!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: there is no LINQ method to retrieve the *index* of the minimum value (not counting `.Aggregate`, which would not be simpler than a loop here). Not saying the whole thing isn't smacking of something simply copied from C, of course, but LINQ isn't really helpful here.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't think that matters. Not when you actually read the book and the reviews. It *is* a VB6 translation with examples that don't compile. The book should simply be ignored. Unless its a required course book and it's not possible to move to a different college AT ONCE. In which case, pass the course and go to a local User Group to actually learn

Comment: @RichardRublev I hope this isn't your course book. If it is, my concolences. Don't try to get smart with the professor - people that use such coursebooks are capable of forcing you to drop out. Play dumb, pass the exam and use Pluralsight's and Coursera's courses to actually *learn* about C# and programming.

Comment: @RichardRublev you can get 3 months free access to Pluralsight's courses through the (free) Visual Studio Dev Essentials program. Look for .NET/C# user groups in your area. Try to find Microsoft's Student partner in your school (it's a guy, not a company, typically a student) and look for further training resources

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes, the book is bad. I'm just saying your particular assertion that the block is superfluous and should be replaced with LINQ is wrong. If you want to pull this to a higher level, we can say this isn't how you implement a priority queue in C# in any case and leave it at that.

Comment: @RichardRublev as for Coursera and edX, the courses are top-notch, but you have to pay to get a certificate. Doesn't matter if you only want to follow the course to learn. Don't look at Udemy or other similar ultra-super-free sites. There's very little quality control and the courses are often stolen from the top sites.

Comment: @JeroenMostert actually, you can if `pqItem` implements IComparable.  Even if it isn't, you can use LINQ operators or your own fliter. MoreLinq has an implementation already - [MinBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) will return the minimum item based on a property, eg `items.MinBy(it=>it.Priority)`. If LINQ provided a `Min` overload that acceps a comparison function `MinBy` wouldn't be needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes,I see the book is terrible.Thanks for help.Actually I am studying on my own.

Comment: @RichardRublev there are a lot of good books and courses. Microsoft's Virtual Academy has a lot of online courses for free. Pluralsight has hundrends, from the best authors. If you want an introduction, the `Head First` books provide a gentle and fun introduction to many subjects

Comment: Will go for Pluralsight.